# Gregorian calendar values different between debugger and System.out.println?

Tags: android, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to work out strange behaviour with a Gregorian Calendar object which has been set to the current time. When I store the values from the Calendar object in a database table the wrong values are being stored, so I put in some System.out.println statements to check all of the properties of the Calendar, as well as running the debugger. The strange thing is that when I hover over the properties in the (Eclipse) debugger window I see the incorrect values which are being written to my database table, but the System.out shows CORRECT values.

I've set a breakpoint in my code to the line AFTER the last System.out.println statement. At this point when I hover over the Calendar variables their values are shown as:

```
Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH = 5
Calendar.MONTH = 2
Calendar.YEAR = 1
```

However the output of the System.out.println statements is below, and shows the values that I was expecting (i.e. August 27th 2014):

```
08-27 10:31:37.986: I/System.out(1528): ERA: 1
08-27 10:31:37.986: I/System.out(1528): YEAR: 2014
08-27 10:31:37.986: I/System.out(1528): MONTH: 8
08-27 10:31:37.996: I/System.out(1528): WEEK_OF_YEAR: 39
08-27 10:31:37.996: I/System.out(1528): WEEK_OF_MONTH: 4
08-27 10:31:37.996: I/System.out(1528): DATE: 27
08-27 10:31:38.009: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_MONTH: 27
08-27 10:31:38.009: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_YEAR: 270
08-27 10:31:38.016: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_WEEK: 7
08-27 10:31:38.016: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH: 4
08-27 10:31:38.027: I/System.out(1528): AM_PM: 0
08-27 10:31:38.027: I/System.out(1528): HOUR: 10
08-27 10:31:38.027: I/System.out(1528): HOUR_OF_DAY: 10
08-27 10:31:38.027: I/System.out(1528): MINUTE: 31
08-27 10:31:38.027: I/System.out(1528): SECOND: 37
08-27 10:31:38.036: I/System.out(1528): MILLISECOND: 982
08-27 10:31:38.036: I/System.out(1528): ZONE_OFFSET: 0
08-27 10:31:38.046: I/System.out(1528): DST_OFFSET: 0
08-27 10:31:58.607: I/System.out(1528): ERA: 1
08-27 10:31:58.607: I/System.out(1528): YEAR: 2014
08-27 10:31:58.626: I/System.out(1528): MONTH: 8
08-27 10:31:58.626: I/System.out(1528): WEEK_OF_YEAR: 39
08-27 10:31:58.626: I/System.out(1528): WEEK_OF_MONTH: 4
08-27 10:31:58.639: I/System.out(1528): DATE: 27
08-27 10:31:58.649: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_MONTH: 27
08-27 10:31:58.657: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_YEAR: 270
08-27 10:31:58.657: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_WEEK: 7
08-27 10:31:58.667: I/System.out(1528): DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH: 4
08-27 10:31:58.676: I/System.out(1528): AM_PM: 0
08-27 10:31:58.687: I/System.out(1528): HOUR: 10
08-27 10:31:58.687: I/System.out(1528): HOUR_OF_DAY: 10
08-27 10:31:58.697: I/System.out(1528): MINUTE: 31
08-27 10:31:58.707: I/System.out(1528): SECOND: 58
08-27 10:31:58.707: I/System.out(1528): MILLISECOND: 606
08-27 10:31:58.727: I/System.out(1528): ZONE_OFFSET: 0
08-27 10:31:58.727: I/System.out(1528): DST_OFFSET: 0
```

My code is below:

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());// set the current
                                                    // time and date for
                                                    // this calendar

// Set date for alarm from current date
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1); // Java calendar months start at zero 

 System.out.println("ERA: " + cal.get(Calendar.ERA));
 System.out.println("YEAR: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
 System.out.println("MONTH: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
 System.out.println("WEEK_OF_YEAR: " +
 cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
 System.out.println("WEEK_OF_MONTH: " +
 cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
 System.out.println("DATE: " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
 System.out.println("DAY_OF_MONTH: " +
 cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 System.out.println("DAY_OF_YEAR: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
 System.out.println("DAY_OF_WEEK: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
 System.out.println("DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH: "
 + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
 System.out.println("AM_PM: " + cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
 System.out.println("HOUR: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
 System.out.println("HOUR_OF_DAY: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
 System.out.println("MINUTE: " + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
 System.out.println("SECOND: " + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
 System.out.println("MILLISECOND: " + cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
 System.out.println("ZONE_OFFSET: "
 + (cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/(60*60*1000)));
 System.out.println("DST_OFFSET: "
 + (cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)/(60*60*1000)));
```

Comment: month starts from index 0 is that the cause of your problem?

Comment: No, I'd already allowed for that in my third cal.set statement